# how to get an error message and save it in a table in sybase?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

```
drop procedure getTitle

create procedure getTitle @title_id VARCHAR(9)
as

declare @error  int,
@title varchar(100)

begin

insert into tab1 (CODE) VALUES (1) jhghjghj --- the jhghjghj  places to cause an error

SELECT @title = description from master..sysmessages where error = @@error
update ex_employee set info = @title
commit
print "%1!", @title
end
go
```

If I try compile this procedure it will give me this error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'jhghjghj'.
```

What I want is to save this message `Incorrect syntax near 'jhghjghj'.`  into a table.
I am trying to catch it in a way . Is that possible ?

Comment: Have you looked at `raiserror` & `sp_addmessage` to define your own errors?  Also, I may be looking at this wrong, but are you trying to capture the error before it actually occurs?  Because the insert is part of the same transaction as the select, the error hasn't occured until the statement ends?

Comment: @MichaelGardner when an error occure , I want to capture it and insert it  into a temp table. I dont want to have my own errors . I want the error that occured when a query have been executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. It is little tricky. Make the query dynamic, so that Syabse wont complain about the syntax error while compile. You compilation will be fine and you will get your desire result in run-time.

```
create procedure getTitle @title_id VARCHAR(9)
as

declare @error  int,
@title varchar(100)

begin

declare @my_query varchar(500)
select @my_query = "insert into tab1 (CODE) VALUES (1) jhghjghj"  
exec (@my_query )

SELECT @title = description from master..sysmessages where error = @@error
update ex_employee set info = @title
commit
print "%1!", @title
end
go
```

Comment: I have a long procedure and I cannot assing data type text @mrinal